# Make 1 hour loop with ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, video

I have a video. I want to loop it continuously and cut it off at exactly 1 hour.
How can I loop the video for exactly 1 hour?

Answer (score 2):

The stream_loop option can do the trick:

```
ffmpeg -stream_loop -1 -i input.mp4 -t 1:00:00 -c copy output.mp4
```

The movie & amovie filters can also do the trick:

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i "movie=filename=input.mp4:loop=0,setpts=N/FRAME_RATE/TB" -f lavfi -i "amovie=filename=input.mp4:loop=0,asetpts=N/SR/TB" -t 1:00:00 output.mp4
```

Partially taken from [llogan's answer](https://video.stackexchange.com/a/12906/38507)